# C drop connection after sending data

Tags: c, sockets

How can I drop connection in plain C after I have sent the data? I have a server which creates socket and waits for connection. After getting connection it sends char array through that socket. After that it should drop the connection and go back to waiting next connection. How can I do that? This is my test code:

```
int main()
{
char str[100];
int listen_fd, comm_fd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(22000);
bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
listen(listen_fd, 10);
comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

while (1)
{
    bzero(str, 100);
    write(comm_fd, str, strlen(str) + 1);
}
}
```

Comment: assuming you don't need to process multiple clients simultaneously, your `accept()` call also needs to be inside a loop.    If you do need to process multiple clients simultaneously, stuff gets a _lot_ harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

while (1)
{
    bzero(str, 100);
    write(comm_fd, str, strlen(str) + 1);
}
```

The code inside the `while` loop is the code that will be repeated constantly...now look where you've placed the call to `accept` the new connection. It's outside of the `while` loop. As your code currently stands, you'll call it once and then constantly send data at the new connection.

If you put the `accept` inside the `while` loop and also `close` that new connection, like the following code, you should get the result you're looking for.

```
while (1)
{
    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
    bzero(str, 100);
    write(comm_fd, str, strlen(str) + 1);
    close(comm_fd);
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick and I also moved the accept part inside the while loop. Thanks.